# I am trying to implent my own strpbrk function in C

Tags: c

The function is supposed to work similarly to the `strpbrk` function in C. When I run the code, I get a segmentation fault. I did  a rubber duck debug yet couldn't figure out any problem with the code. I am using a *gcc compiler on WSL*. The main.h header file contains the function declaration `char *_strpbrk(char *s, char *accept)`. Please what am I missing?

```
#include "main.h"

/**
 * _strpbrk - searches the string s for any of a set of bytes
 *
 * @s: String to be searched
 * @accept: Substring of bytes to search for
 * Return: Return a pointer to the byte in s that matches one of the bytes in
 * accept, or NULL if no such byte is found
 */

char *_strpbrk(char *s, char *accept)
{
    int i, j, check = 0, position = 0;

    i = 0;
    while (*(s + i) != '\0')
    {
        for (j = 0; *(accept + j) != '\0'; j++) /* Check if character of s in focus is a character in accept. Break out of the for loop if true*/
        {
            if (*(s + i) == *(accept + j))
            {
                check = 1;
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (check == 1) /* check if the character of s in focus was found to be in accept. Break out of the while loop if true */
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (position == 0) /* Check for return value. Return null if whole string traversed*/
    {
        return ('\0');
    }
    else
    {
        return (s + position);
    }
}
```

Forgot to mention that the `gcc` flags `-Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra -std=gnu89` are used during compilation.

Comment: What is the input to this function?

Comment: And did you also try the `gdb` debugger? Maybe figure out where the program crashes and what the values of your program are at that time? I am not questioning the proficiency of the duck, but you may be using the wrong tool for this particular job.

Comment: The termination condition in the `j` loop is wrong. The `i` loop and the `j` loop should be identical except for the name changes. And stop using garbage like `*(s + i)`. It's `s[i]`.

Comment: What happen if the substring is found at position 0, you return `NULL`?

Comment: As Aamir already hinted at, your function will also Segfault if you pass a NULL pointer to that function. Your second loop is also wrong, as user3386109 already said, however it will likely not segfault either, because it will not run at all `(j = 0; j != 0; ++j)` => No execution, `j` is now `1`.

Comment: `position` _can_ legitimately be zero. Do: `int position = -1;` Then: `if (position < 0) return NULL; else return &s[position];`

Comment: Why not use two `for`-loops and write `for (int i = 0; *(s + i) != '\0' i++)`?

Comment: OP lost interest as I see.

Comment: @user3386109 pardon my use of *(s + i). I'm still trying to wrap my head around pointers. This makes it easier for me to read at the moment

Comment: @RefugnicEternium I made an edit to the code. It should be `(j = 0; *(accept + j) != '\0'; j++)`

Comment: Please don't edited questions as you go along. It's no help to a future reader if the question doesn't even exhibit the problem.

Answer (score 3):

1. Do not use `_` as a prefix.
2. This task shows how useful is use of the functions

```
char *mystrchr(const char *str, const char c)
{
    while(*str)
    {
        if(*str == c) return (char *)str;
        str++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

char *mystrbrk(const char *str, const char *brk)
{
    while(*str)
    {
        if(mystrchr(brk, *str)) return (char *)str;
        str++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Now your code:

```
return ('\0');
```

This is not returning pointer. You are lucky as `'\0'` will convert to pointer NULL. Basically, it is very hard to analyze as you overthink many things.

Comment: Please the compilation is done with `gcc` flags `-Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra -std=gnu89`. I'm not supposed to use recursion since technically I don't know what it is yet.

Comment: I don't see any recursion happening there, actually. Just one function calling another.

Comment: If you don't know what recursion is yet, click here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73479266/i-am-trying-to-implent-my-own-strpbrk-function-in-c#comment129773149_73479488

Comment: @AfayedorMawuliArnold it will compile - try yourself

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "main.h"

/**
 * _strpbrk - searches the string s for any of a set of bytes
 *
 * @s: String to be searched
 * @accept: Substring of bytes to search for
 * Return: Return a pointer to the byte in s that matches one of the bytes in
 * accept, or NULL if no such byte is found
 */

char *_strpbrk(char *s, char *accept)
{
    int i, j, check = 0, position = 0;

    i = 0;
    while (*(s + i) != '\0')
    {
        for (j = 0; *(accept + j) != '\0'; j++) /* Check if character of s in focus is a character in accept. Break out of the for loop if true*/
        {
            if (*(s + i) == *(accept + j))
            {
                check = 1;
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (check == 1) /* check if the character of s in focus was found to be in accept. Break out of the while loop if true */
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (position == 0) /* Check for return value. Return null if whole string traversed*/
    {
        return ('\0');
    }
    else
    {
        return (s + position);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem was with the `j loop`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).